# knockout: be notified when a component is injected into the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, knockout.js

I'm writing my first knockout custom component. In that I'm using as a template a string with some html and I'd like to enhance this html via jquery. Do to that I don't actually know when the custom template is injected into the DOM I'd like to have a callback responding on an event fired after the DOM injection and after the binding is applied (I'm using a `foreach` binding).

I've tried to read [this manual page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#example-2-a-component-loader-that-loads-external-files-using-custom-code) on custom loader but I think it should be an easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

Don't fiddle with the DOM outside of a binding handler. If you want some variable HTML injected, use [the html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a 'widget' binding and use that in your component model/template

I implemented something like that a while ago: https://gist.github.com/osbornm/5043549